# Memory de-allocation with std::vector re-assignment

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have `VectorA` and `VectorB` are two `std::vector<SameType>`, both initilized (i mean `VectorA.size() > 0` and `VectorB.size() > 0`)

If I do:

```
VectorA = VectorB;
```

the memory previosly allocated for `VectorA` is automatically freed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is freed in the sense that the destructors of all contained objects are called, and the vector no longer owns the memory.<sup>1</sup>

But really, it's just returned to the [allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_(C%2B%2B)), which may or may not actually return it to the OS.

So long as there isn't a bug in the allocator being used, you haven't created a memory leak, if that's what your concern is.

---

<sub>1. As @David points out in the comment below, the memory isn't necessarily deallocated, depending on whether the size needs to change or not.</sub>

Comment: Assignment does not need to reallocate, copy and deallocate the old buffer if the destination vector has enough capacity. It does not need to destroy the old objects either, but can rather use the *assignment operator* to *rewrite* the first `min( v1.size(), v2.size() )` elements (assuming that it does not need to reallocate.

Answer (score 2):

In general, *not necessarily*. When you assign one vector to the other, the post condition is that both arrays will contain *equivalent* objects at the end of the operation.

If the `capacity` of the destination vector is enough, the operation can be achieved by calling the *assignment operator* on the set of `min( v1.size(), v2.size() )` elements, and then either destructing the rest of the elements if the destination vector held more elements, or else *copy-constructing* the extra elements at the end. In this case no memory release or allocation will be done.

If the destination vector does not have enough capacity, then it will create a new buffer with enough capacity and *copy-construct* the elements in the new buffer from the source vector. It will then swap the old and new buffers, destroy all old objects and release the old buffer. In this case, the old objects *are* destroyed and the old memory released, but this is just one case.